# Mysql join 3 tables and count 1 of them so there is no duplicates Opencart 2+

Tags: mysql, left-join, opencart

Ok, I am making a custom plugin for a client and we are trying to generate a custom order report in Opencart 2+

The problem I am having is in the mysql query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
  opt.value,
  ( SELECT  COUNT(*) 
     FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_option` optb 
     WHERE optb.order_id = o.order_id
  ) AS duplicate_count, 
  SUM(op.quantity * duplicate_count) AS quantity, 
  SUM((op.total + op.tax) * op.quantity) AS total 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op 
LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) 
LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_option` opt ON (op.order_id = opt.order_id) 
WHERE opt.name = 'Include Logo' AND opt.value != 'No Logo'
";
```

I am trying to join the info from 3 tables.
1. order
2. order_product
3. order_option

Normally opencart will show you a report of how many products were sold, etc. when you run a report.  We are trying to generate a report that will give a report of how many of a specific option was ordered  opt.value != 'No Logo'

Unfortunately I do not have much experience joining tables.
All help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please add a link to opencart db structure. This way someone who's not fimilar with opencart could also help you.

Comment: Creating an SQL fiddle or at least tested DML and SQL for this would be conducive to a usable answer.  Otherwise we can't work out the query.

Comment: Here is a sample of the tables.  To big to add it to a fiddle: https://justpaste.it/szga